# Where can I search components according characteristics, not model?

Tags: components, datasheet, component-selection, development-tools

I'm 2 years disconnected of electronics, and i don't know how i get and know the components i used, and i want to get and know few more components, but i can't get to know them... and well i was wondering if there is some search engine or database where they are classified according characteristics... i never got to know anything like that, only the books... but if there are books, they certainly are some sites of it... i just can't find them...

Is there a Component search engine where i can search according the characteristics of a certain component?
For example, gain and power of an OpAmp?, or an integrate circuit for ADC and DAC, 
certain gate current of a FET, etc etc etc...

Comment: Have you tried parametric search on component distributors like digikey.com or mouser.com. I bet there are more. Google for "electronics parametric search components" and you'll find countless smaller and larger sites.

Answer (score 5):

Most manufacturers have parametric search engines. For example, [here](https://www.microchip.com/ParamChartSearch/chart.aspx?branchID=1005)'s Microchip's. Usually name and `parametric search` will help.

Many electronics retailers also have parametric search, for example [here](http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en)'s Digikey's search. There, you just select type of component and later on, apply filter types for each characteristic of the component.

Comment: Good point to mention the component manufacturers themselves too.

Comment: Perfect that was what i was looking for, the next step is to learn how to use the parametric search, thanks...

Comment: @ekiim Have fun and keep in mind that learning how they operate is a very useful skill!

Comment: thanks, actually i'm on it right know, its fun, and useful haha, thanks...

Comment: is there a way, to have a local copy of the database? with some program to open it?

Comment: @ekiim I'm not sure of that actually. If there is such program, I haven't found it or heard of anyone using it so far.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the good answer of @AndrejaKo, you could also get yourself a copy of the book:

[The Art of Electronics (3rd edition)](http://artofelectronics.net/).

Not only it is an excellent book on every aspect of electronics design, but it also contains dozens of tables with comparison data between components. The 3rd edition has just been published (2015), and it is very up to date. That book also teach you *how* to select components and *why* to do one choice instead of another.